# incoming request error from python to flask

Tags: python, flask

I passing a request from python to flask. I am not able to access the requests which are being sent from python in flask. 
Here is my python function -

```
import requests

dice_roll = 1
dealear_roll = 2

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/dice'
data = {'dice_roll':dice_roll,'dealear_roll':dealear_roll}
r = requests.post(url=url,data=data)
```

Here is flask api

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import random
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/dice')
def dice_roll():

    dice_roll = request.args.get('dice_roll')
    dealear_roll = request.args.get('dealear_roll')

    print('dice_roll',dice_roll)
    print('dealear_roll',dealear_roll)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I am not able to access the requests in flask. Can anyone tell where am i doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure if this is the only problem, but you using `dealear_roll` and `dealer_roll` - i.e. different keys

Comment: @buran I updated the variable now. You can check the question. Even though the same error

Comment: same error does not tell us much. post the full traceback you get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `request.form.get` instead of `request.args.get`

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import random
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/dice', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def dice_roll():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        dice_roll = request.form.get('dice_roll')
        dealear_roll = request.form.get('dealear_roll')

        print('dice_roll', dice_roll)
        print('dealear_roll', dealear_roll)
    return ''



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: I changed to form.get from args.get but It is not printing any response. When I am killing the program then it is printing the response but not when sending a request.

Comment: wait let me check

Comment: on my system it works fine.

Comment: I am using GITBash to compile the program. Will there be any problem?

Comment: i don't know about that, may be you should try to run on other than gitbash

Comment: I tested in linux and it is working. Thanks a lot @Nihal

Answer (score 0):

You need to add method handler in the route of GET, POST like this..

```
@app.route('/dice', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def dice_roll():

    dice_roll = request.args.get('dice_roll')
    dealer_roll = request.args.get('dealer_roll')

    print('dice_roll',dice_roll)
    print('dealer_roll',dealer_roll)
```